# Can't install software via Ubuntu GUI. Neither Snap Store (orange icon) nor GNOME Software (blue icon) are able to search or show any installed apps.c

Tags: networking, software-center, proxy

The "Explore" tab loads properly for both. "Installed" is just empty. "Updates" says "Software is up to date"

I'm behind a proxy server at work running Ubuntu 20.04 on a Dell desktop.

Of note, when I open the "Software & Updates" app then click on the "Livepatch" tab, it tells me "Livepatch requires an internet connection."

I've already configured and updated my proxy info in the terminal and under Settings -> Network. There it does show a working wired connection.

I have been able to download software on the terminal without issues.

Output of sudo apt update:

```
Ign:1 https://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable InRelease
Ign:2 https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-deb/releases/download/apt-get ./ InRelease                        
Err:3 https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-deb/releases/download/apt-get ./ Release                          
  Could not handshake: An unexpected TLS packet was received. [IP: 10.30.0.112 8080]
Err:4 https://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable Release                                      
  Could not handshake: An unexpected TLS packet was received. [IP: 10.30.0.112 8080]
Hit:5 http://mirror.wiru.co.za/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                        
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/smathot/cogscinl/ubuntu focal InRelease                  
Hit:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                            
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:9 http://mirror.wiru.co.za/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:10 http://mirror.wiru.co.za/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-deb/releases/download/apt-get ./ Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Output of sudo snap install hello-world

```
error: unable to contact snap store
```

After writing these command I got a different error:

sudo snap set system proxy.http="http://10.10.110.128:8888/"

sudo snap set system proxy.https="http://10.10.110.128:8888/"

```
error: cannot install "hello-world": Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: proxyconnect
       tcp: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
```

Did I make the problem better or worse?

Comment: Looking at your `sudo apt update` output, your sources are messed up. You should correct the errors and remove sources that are no longer viable.  See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file

Comment: working great now, thanks!